# Wordpress meta-box and checkbox-list

Tags: plugins, metabox

I have a trouble with a type of checkbox-list in meta-box.
This is my code in **meta-box-config.php**:

```
$meta_boxes[] = array(
'id'        => 'poker_room_extension',
'title'     => 'Poker Room Options',
'pages'     => array( 'post', 'page' ),

'fields'    => array(

    array(
        'name'      => 'Sistema operativo supportato',
        'id'        => $prefix . 'os_poker_room',
        'clone'     => false,
        'type'      => 'checkbox_list',
        'options'   => array(
            'windows'     => 'Windows ',
            'mac' => 'Mac ',
            'linux' => 'Linux '
        ),
        'std'       => false
    )
)
 );
```

This is what I see in my post's options

[image]

[image]

Is it normal that variable omc_os_poker_room is the same? How I can show the values? Is omc_os_poker_room an array or not? I don't understand.

If I run this code in my template it show only the first value (windows and not the other ones checked):

```
$omc_os_poker_room =  get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'omc_os_poker_room', true);
$conta = count($omc_os_poker_room);

        <?php if ($omc_os_poker_room != '') {
            echo '<p class="omc-info-one"><b>OS: </b>';
            for($i=0;$i<$conta;$i++) {
            echo $omc_os_poker_room[$i];
            } }?>
```

Can you help me?
Thanks

I replaced this line:

```
$omc_os_poker_room =  get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'omc_os_poker_room', true);
```

to

```
$omc_os_poker_room =  get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'omc_os_poker_room', false);
```

It's working now! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is probably with the `$single` parameter of `get_post_meta` function. Try setting it to `false` or delete it. [Codex Link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta#Parameters)

Then,

```
$omc_os_poker_room =  get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'omc_os_poker_room');
    echo '<p class="omc-info-one"><b>OS: '.$omc_os_poker_room[1].'</b>';
```

Not tested, but should work.